# Printing even and odd number using two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written below program to print even and odd numbers:

```
public class PrintEvenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CurrentValue currentValue = new CurrentValue();
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new PrintOdd(10, currentValue));
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new PrintEven(10, currentValue));
        oddThread.start();
        evenThread.start();
    }

}

class CurrentValue {

    private int current = 0;

    public int getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Integer current) {
        this.current = current;
    }
}


class PrintOdd implements Runnable {

    private int noOfValuesToPrint;
    private CurrentValue currentValue;

    public PrintOdd(int noOfValuesToPrint, CurrentValue currentValue) {
        this.noOfValuesToPrint = noOfValuesToPrint;
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (currentValue) {
                System.out.println("Inside Print odd");
                int current = currentValue.getCurrent();
                System.out.println("Value of current in odd is " + current);
                while (current % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Value of current in odd is " + current + "and value of current % 2  is "
                                + current % 2);
                        System.out.println("odd waiting");
                        currentValue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Odd no. is " + ++current);
                currentValue.setCurrent(current);
                currentValue.notify();
                System.out.println("Notify executed from odd");
            }
        }
    }
}

class PrintEven implements Runnable {

    private int noOfValuesToPrint;
    private CurrentValue currentValue;

    public PrintEven(int noOfValuesToPrint, CurrentValue currentValue) {
        this.noOfValuesToPrint = noOfValuesToPrint;
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (currentValue) {
                System.out.println("Inside Print even");
                int current = currentValue.getCurrent();
                System.out.println("Value of current in even is " + current);
                while (current % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("even waiting");
                        currentValue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Even no. is " + ++current);
                currentValue.setCurrent(current);
                currentValue.notify();
                System.out.println("Notify executed from even");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Output it gives me is:

**Inside Print odd**

**Value of current in odd is 0**

**Odd no. is 1**

**Notify executed from odd**

**Inside Print odd**

**Value of current in odd is 1**

**Value of current in odd is 1and value of current % 2  is 1**

**odd waiting**

**Inside Print even**

**Value of current in even is 1**

**Even no. is 2**

**Notify executed from even**

**Inside Print even**

**Value of current in even is 2**

**even waiting**

**Value of current in odd is 1and value of current % 2  is 1**

**odd waiting**

I am expecting both threads to print even and odd numbers taking turns using `wait` and `notify` mechanism. What am I doing wrong? I also tried with making the `current` variable volatile, but it gives the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this condition `while (current % 2 != 0)` (and opposite one in `PrintEven`) value of `current` is not updated. Use `while (currentValue.getCurrent() % 2 != 0)` instead; get rid of the `current` variable or update it in the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling on this for 2 hours. It works after using currentValue.getCurrent() . One question though, Once the other thread executes notify, from which line will the notified thread's run method will start executing?

Comment: @Aman You're welcome! From the next line after it called `wait`.